# EasyAR camera flash

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, easyar

using EasyAR with unity 3d

i wanted to enable camera flash

i have used this code but it didnt work

it shows me errors in these line

**cameraDevice.CameraParameters.FlashTorchMode**

Error   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for '**FlashTorchMode**' and no accessible extension method '**FlashTorchMode**' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using UnityEngine;
using easyar;

public class FlashController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CameraDeviceBehaviour cameraDevice;

    private void Start()
    {

        // Get the CameraDeviceBehaviour component
        cameraDevice = GetComponent<CameraDeviceBehaviour>();
    }

    public void EnableFlash()
    {
        // Enable the flash
        cameraDevice.CameraParameters.FlashTorchMode = true;
    }

    public void DisableFlash()
    {
        // Disable the flash
        cameraDevice.CameraParameters.FlashTorchMode = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching in the [API - Version 4.6](https://help.easyar.com/EasyAR%20Sense%20Unity%20Plugin/latest/) (always your first best friend in such cases) I can only see [`CameraDevice.setFlashTorchMode`](https://help.easyar.com/EasyAR%20Sense%20Unity%20Plugin/latest/ApiReference/Sense/CameraDevice.html#setflashtorchmode) which is a **method** not a property.

I think it was like that already before (at least down to the docs of 1.3 I found) so you probably rather have to use

```
public void EnableFlash()
{
    // Enable the flash
    cameraDevice.Device.setFlashTorchMode(true);
}

public void DisableFlash()
{
    // Disable the flash
    cameraDevice.Device.setFlashTorchMode(false);
}
```

**Note that in earlier versions the method started upper case, in later ones lower case.**

Didn't find any `CameraDeviceBehaviour` though .. only in older versions  [`CameraDeviceBaseBehaviour`](https://help.easyar.com/EasyAR%20Sense/v2/Unity%20Plugin%20Reference/CameraDeviceBaseBehaviour.html) e.g. in v2 so you seem to either use an older version or are doing something wrong ;)

In the newer the equivalent seems to be [`CameraDeviceFrameSource`](https://help.easyar.com/EasyAR%20Sense%20Unity%20Plugin/latest/ApiReference/CameraDeviceFrameSource.html).

The error message you show us indicates that the compiler doesn't even know `cameraDevice.CameraParameters` or maybe already `CameraDeviceBehaviour`. Otherwise it would say

```
Error CS1061 'TheExactClass' does not contain ...
```

instead of the general `object`. So there have to be some more errors you didn't show us.